# Automated builds over cloud using custom dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, continuous-integration, travis-ci, dependency-management

We have an on-premise infrastructure with git repository, a CI server and an artifact repository. We are using gradle in our project. This is working perfectly fine for our regular CICD processes.

We are planning to move our code to cloud using private Github and Travis-CI for CI. The problem is that we have a couple of third party jars that are not available in any artifact repositories on the internet, e.g. maven central and others. The on-premise infrastructure worked fine as we had manually installed those jar files in our internal artifact repository.

Our builds on travis are now failing. What is the best way to provide these third party jars to travis during build time?

P.S.: The third party jars are drivers provided by some of our vendors. These are not open source and cannot be pushed to artifact repositories on the internet.

Comment: why not use Jenkins for CI?, it will give you full control over the process..

Comment: We have already made a decision on using travis-ci on the cloud. I don't quite remember why we chose travis over jenkins. The decision was made a while back.